# Convert string to Datetime by TryParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime

How do I convert a `string` to a `DateTime` using TryParseExact?

For example:

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDateTime, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

Comment: You've already shown an example. What's the problem/question?

Comment: try with `stringDateTime="2013.05.14 09:00:00";`

Comment: What is your problem? what is in stringDateTime variable?

Comment: This is neither a question nor an answer.

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it...

Comment: I have error when converting

Comment: Please state your error, and provide your `stringDateTime`. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/about for more information on how SO works, and that you need to provide quality questions to get quality answers.

Comment: How about we try to help the user make this a better question before flagging to close it?

Comment: @peter that's not how it works. Bad questions should be closed immediately. They can be reopened if they ever get improved.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, ok, always thought differently. I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

When you use `TryParseExact` or `ParseExact` the input string **must** be in the format which you are trying to parse it as. So in your example, if `stringDateTime` is not in the format of `yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss` then it won't work i.e.

```
var stringDateTime = "01/01/2013 12:00:00";
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDateTime, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date); // will return false

stringDateTime = "2013.01.01 20:00:00";
DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDateTime, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date); // will return true
```