# Best practice to parse date from string

Tags: c#, datetime

What is the best practice (in C#) to turn a string in the format

```
Mon, 27 Oct 2014 15:21:24 GMT
```

into a valid `DateTime`?

Comment: `TryParseExact()`; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx

Comment: Well, best practices would be to never find yourself in that position... Too many things could go wrong. Try to ensure you always deal with ISO8601 date strings to make life bearable for you. Also, ensure you only use UTC, to avoid timezone issues (if you ever want to have an international application). Try to get the TimeZone information (-05:00 or so) in your date string to be totally sure what you are dealing with.

Comment: Where this date comes from? If it comes from a Database, getting this date as a string to parse is a very bad practice.

Comment: this string comes from a third party web service so i can't control it. i thought that TryParseExact() won't hanlde this but i weas wrong. this seems to work fine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to Datetime by TryParseExact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538534/convert-string-to-datetime-by-tryparseexact)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.RFC1123Pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```